# Save collection of object using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework for accessing my database.

In the migration, I see that 2 tables were created:

1. Shop 2. Product

I created a shop and added product to the shop.Products - but when doing this I see in the database that only shop-changed propereis are saved

- and the product table is empty.

Do I need to have one more `DbSet<Product>` and same the product to this table?

Or there is another way to do it?

I am writing my code in C# and running on .NET Core 8.

```
 public class MyContext: DbContext
 {
     public DbSet<Shop> ShopItems { get; set; }
 }

 public class Shop
 {
     [Key]
     public string UniqId {get;set;}
     public List<Product> Products {get;set;}
 }

 public class Product
 {
     [Key]
     public string UniqId {get;set;}
     public double Price {get;set;}
     public String Name {get;set;}
 }
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Comment: the code example is in the question

Comment: No it isn't. "I created shop and added product to the Products." There's the problem so that's relevant code.

Comment: @GertArnold sorry, but this is the code. the question is simple - how to save changes when i add Product to Shop.Product - because from what i see on the Product table , the changes are not saved.    if you have an answer so please tell me.

Comment: Does it really not occur to you that we need to see how you do that? Of course it's just adding a product to that collection and call SaveChanges. Except, it apparently isn't. Anyway, it's fine with me, happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you have two tables "ShopItems" and "ProductItems", with a EF one-to-many relation: **Shop** entity is the "parent", **Product** entity is the "child". To handle them with EF, you have to use two different DbSets. It doesn't matter if you don't want to use the "ProductItems" table directly to handle your products, because you will find them in the **List** you find in the Shop class, and, briefly, your products will be updated, saved, deleted, when you save the "Shop" (parent) entity having "this list inside".

You have to define, also, the foreign key from Product to Shop, because the Product must know to which Shop it belongs to.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Shop> ShopItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> ProductItems { get; set; }
}

public class Shop
{
    [Key]
    public string UniqId {get;set;}
    public List<Product> Products {get;set;}
}

public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public string UniqId {get;set;}
    public double Price {get;set;}
    public String Name {get;set;}
    public string ShopId {get;set;} //foreign key
    public Shop Shop {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Well, the `DbSet<Shop>` isn't necessary because `Product` is reachable through `Shop` and EF already maps the class. Neither is `ShopId` necessary. It's *easier* to have them, but OP's code could have worked without them, but as you see above, they didn't deem it necessary to have their existing code corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `DbSet<Product>` to `MyContext`

```
 public class MyContext : DbContext
 {
     public DbSet<Shop> ShopItems { get; set; }
     public DbSet<Product> ProductItems { get; set; }
 }

 public class Shop
 {
     [Key]
     public string UniqId {get;set;}
     public List<Product> Products {get;set;}
 }

 public class Product
 {
     [Key]
     public string UniqId {get;set;}
     public double Price {get;set;}
     public String Name {get;set;}
 }
```

if this doesn't help could you please provide the client code? (the code where you add the products)

P.S. DbSet is not required, you should add foreign key for Product: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships

Comment: add the DbSet<Product> work - but the question was how to do it without have one more DbSet. becaue now, with this one more DbSet<Product> i need to do more code to add / read / update to this DbSet - and not just update the Shop object 

i will need to write/read to this DbSet

Comment: there is no client code - this is server side. 
calling Shop.Products .Add(...) and then SaveChange() - suppose to save the product

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice. Your Product entity hasn't foreign key, try to add this. Here you can read about it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships